# Changing color of an id with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I get all movie datas from Firebase and also i get score of the movies. If the score of the movie is higher than 70, then i will change color of the id as "deepskyblue", if it is 50 or higher it will be "orange" and lastly if it is lower than 50 it will be "crimson"(red). When i do this, it only changes my first movie's id's color. But i wanna change all of them. How can i do this?

**My Website**

[image: My Website]

**Console.log(i)**

[image: console]

```js
var movieNo = 0;
let html = '';
var body = document.getElementById('editor');
var body2 = document.getElementById('week');

function AddItemsToTable(name, score, img, id) {
  var movies = `<div class="content"><img src="${img}" ><p><a href="Admin.html?movieId=${id}">${name}</a></p> <p> <i class="fa fa-star" id="star"></i>&nbsp;<a class="scoretxt">${score}</a> </p> </div>`;
  html = movies;

  body.innerHTML += html;
  body2.innerHTML += html;

}


function AddAllItemsToTable(TheMovies) {
  movieNo = 0;
  var counter = 0;

  TheMovies.forEach(element => {
    if (counter === 6) {
      return;
    }
    AddItemsToTable(element.movieName, element.movieScore, element.movieImage, element.movieId);
    var i = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-star")[element.movieId];
    console.log(i);
    if (element.movieScore >= 70) {
      i.style.color = "deepskyblue"; //good movie

    } else if (element.movieScore >= 50) {
      i.style.color = "orange"; //not bad
    } else {
      i.style.color = "crimson"; //bad movie
    }

    counter++;

  });

}

function getAllDataOnce() {
  const dbRef = ref(db);
  get(child(dbRef, "Movies"))
    .then((snapshot) => {
      var movies = [];
      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        movies.push(childSnapshot.val())
      });
      AddAllItemsToTable(movies);
    });
}
window.onload = getAllDataOnce;
```

```html
<div class="body" id="body">

  <div class="baslik">Opening This Week</div>
  <div class="baslik2"><a href="series.html">See all</a></div>
  <div id="week">

  </div>
  <div class="baslik">Editor's Picks</div>
  <div class="baslik2"><a href="movies.html">See all</a></div>
  <div id="editor">

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet gives console errors. Please fix to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change the logic.
Your mistake is that you use the same id several times, and it should be unique (1 element = 1 unique id).

Try to make it like this:

```
// AddAllItemsToTable function

if (element.movieScore >= 50 && element.movieScore < 70 ) {
    i.classList.add("deepskyblue"); // good movie
} else if (element.movieScore >= 70) {
    i.classList.add("orange"); // not bad
} else {
    i.classList.add("crimson"); // bad movie
}
```

After that, add the following rules to your styles file:

```
.deepskyblue {
    color: deepskyblue;
}

.orange {
    color: orange;
}

.crimson {
    color: crimson;
}
```

Everything will work as it should and as a bonus it will be easier to manage styles and and you won't have to fix JS code for this.

Comment: that didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Make a function

NOTE IDs need to be unique

```js
const scoreColor = score => {
  const color =  "crimson"
  if (score >= 70) return "deepskyblue"; //good movie
  if (score >= 50) return "orange"; //not bad
  return score;
};

function AddItemsToTable(name, score, img, id) {
  const movies = `<div class="content">
    <img src="${img}" >
    <p><a href="Admin.html?movieId=${id}">${name}</a></p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-star"></i>&nbsp;<a class="${scoreColor(score)}">${score}</a></p> 
    </div>`;
  body.innerHTML += movies;
  body2.innerHTML += movies;

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work but didnt get any error either